# After filtering, adding a cell's value to the maximum valued cell (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use Excel VBA but i couldn't accomplish writing the code.

First I want to filter B column with letters "A" and "D" and D column with letters "S" and "A".

After that in H column I want to find to maximum valued cell and add that cell a specific cell's value (like Sheet2!C2).

It would be a great help if this is done. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more info.

Thank you.

NOTE: I want to overwrite the maximum cell after adding Sheet2!C2. I don't want to sum those cells in another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUBTOTAL(104,H:H)+Sheet2!C2
```

**EDIT#1:**

If instead we want to scan down column **H**, locate the maximum visible value in that column and then add something to it, we would use this *VBA* macro:

```
Sub FixTheMax()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant, rr As Range
    v = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("H:H").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    mx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(r)

    For Each rr In r
        If rr.Value = mx Then
            rr.Value = rr.Value + v
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next rr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what i meant.

Comment: Thanks. That would do it.